# Comparing two distributions using t-test and confidence intervalls

Tags: distributions, t-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have two distributions (see histograms below) and I would like to know, whether they are significantly different (let's say alpha=0.05). The sample size is n=500 in both cases (obtained by bootstrapping). Given the high number of samples, I defined the 2.5th and the 97.5th percentile as the the bounds of the 95% confidence interval of the mean (dashed lines in the histograms). Since both confidence intervals clearly overlap, I would have assumed on first view that there is no significant difference between the two distributions. However, the p-value of the t-test is extremely low (~10^-21), which means, as far as I know, that there is basically no chance that the null hypothesis of the t-test (means are the same) is true (I know that this is not the formal definition of the p-value, but given such a low value, it comes down to the same conclusion result). I also ran a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test which basically yielded the same result as the t-test. Based on the two tests I would conclude that the distributions are significantly different, but why is the overlap between the distributions so big if it is almost certain that they are different?

Edit: My main interest is the probability whether the mean value is signicantly different between the two distributions, so the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is more an addition. Given the result of the t-test, these distributions should be considered 'different'. My question is why is this the case when the two distributions show such a big overlap?

Edit: I fitted the original dataset with a polynomial. The intersection of the polynomial with the x-Axis is the value I'm interested in. The distributions show this value for different bootstrap samples of the original dataset. The first distribution uses the first-order polynomial, the second one the second-order polynomial. I'd like to know whether the determined intersection differs significantly for the different polynomials.

[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Comment: You need to be more specific what you exactly mean by "different". The t-test is a test of means, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test tests the null hypothesis that both samples were drawn from the same distribution (here, sampling distributions). You already see that these tests do not test the same thing. What are you actually interested in?

Comment: You misunderstand the confidence interval (CI). A CI is a range of values that you have 95% confidence contains a computed value, usually the mean. That is simplistic (the full explanation takes pages) but the CI is NOT the range that contains 95% of the values. The CI of the mean is much narrower than that (how much narrower depends on sample size).

Comment: @Matthias , can you be a little more precise with what values you are using ?  1) I'm assuming that your histograms present the bootstrapped *mean* values.  2) What values are you using for your *t*-test ?  You aren't bootstrapping 500 bootstrapped values and passing them to a *t*-test, are you ?

Comment: You use different number of bins, different breaks and different x-axis limits for these two histograms. Obviously, you want to use a test and not the histograms to compare the distributions. But still -- these histograms are "designed" to make the distribution look different.

Comment: @dipetkov I am surprised they look different to you. You're right about the bins and the x-Axis,but they still look extremely similar to me, which is why I am so confused that the tests are so decisive that they are different.

Comment: I admit, it's my subjective opinion that the histograms are different "enough". (The sample size is large also, so small practical differences might be statistically significant.) That's why we have tests and we don't rely on histogram "looks". Why put two histograms next to each other if they are not easy to compare?